# How much power consume by GPS application?

Tags: java, android, mobile, gps

Hey I want to know per minute power consumption by gps location application for android in Samsung galaxy II. when application is running and also when application is running in background? Is there any method that I can test it if my application frequently provide location update and send it to the server. 
Also I want to know in above scenario what is the good time interval that I set for  MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES for requestLocationUpdates of LocationManager.

Comment: This depends on so many factors. The only way to really find out is to run tests yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this app would help. It seems to specifically have a measurement for how much power the GPS is using. If you turn off other apps using GPS, you might be able to get a good handle on the battery consumption.

http://gigaom.com/mobile/android-power-consumption-app/